# Is there muscle hyperplasia or hypertrophy after surgery?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology

After exercise there is hypertrophy only. I am curious, if a surgery removes muscle, will there be hyperplasia or hypertrophy to restore it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It does not required much research to find the answer. After injury and surgery the muscle undergoes inflammation to clear up the debris. After that myogenic cells start to proliferate and differentiate, so as expected, there is hyperplasia by restoring injured muscle. Which means that the body can fully restore muscle function if the injury is not too severe.

- [Effective fiber hypertrophy in satellite cell-depleted skeletal muscle.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21828094)
- [Cellular and Molecular Regulation of Muscle Regeneration](https://www.physiology.org/doi/abs/10.1152/physrev.00019.2003)
- [Regeneration of mammalian skeletal muscle. Basic mechanisms and clinical implications.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20041823)

I investigated this a little bit further. Muscle regrowth is mediated by the BM (basement membrane) which is the extracellular matrix that sorrounds the muscle fiber. If that is badly damaged or the nerve is cut, then the muscle fiber won't grow back and we will get scar tissue instead. The muscle will compensate this at a certain level by hypertrophy. There is an interesting new treatment for severe muscle injury, which removes the scar tissue and adds pig extracellular matrix to regrow the muscle.

- [Implant Lets Patients Regrow Lost Leg Muscle](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/526996/implant-lets-patients-regrow-lost-leg-muscle/)

Comment: "Which means that the body can fully restore muscle function if the injury is not too severe" – as far as I remember, connective tissue proliferates a lot faster and most of the damage is "hot-fixed" that way, that is musles do not fully regenerate their physical capacity, unless the damage is very localised and limited. I might be wrong though: I only had two basic courses on morphology and histology many years ago.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Well we can find it out.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I read yesterday that muscle can grow back if the basement membrane is not removed. I just need to read a little bit more in the topic.

Comment: @EliKorvigo As far as I remember healing has nothing to do with how fast a tissue type proliferates. It depends on what type of stem cells you have and what signal they get. But maybe I am wrong. I have only superficial knowlegde in the topic.